# Convert ViewQuery to KQL

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any regex or pattern to convert ViewQuery to KQL.

Example:

ViewQuery:

```
<d:ViewQuery>
    <Where>
        <And> 
            <And> 
                <Eq> <FieldRef Name="Editor" />
                    <Value Type="User">XXX</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Document Type" />
                    <Value Type="Text">Audit</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Base Content" />
                    <Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
                </Eq>   
        </And>
    </Where>                    
</d:ViewQuery>
```

KQL:

```
k= ((Editor:XXX AND Document Type:Audit) AND Base Content:Document)
```

Please help me